# How should I filter across multiple ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

My non_toxic_items() method does not return the 'correct' set.

Currently,

```
Item.inventory.all()
```

returns **less** than

```
Item.inventory.non_toxic_items()
```

Here is my manager with the problematic method. See the explanation in the function for what I would like it to return.

```
#manager.py
from django.db import models


class InventoryManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(InventoryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            shipment__isnull=True, )

    def non_toxic_items(self):
        """
        Return all non-toxic items, not part of a shipment.

        As python code::

    context['my_qs'] = []
    for batch in self.object_list:
        flag = False
        for input in batch.input_set.all():
            if input.material.type.is_toxic:
                flag=True
        if not flag:
            for item in batch.item_set.all():
                if item.shipment is None:
                    context['my_qs'].append(item)
        """
        return super(InventoryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            # BUG -- Does not return the same queryset as above python code.
            shipment__isnull=True,
            batch__input__material__type__is_toxic=False).distinct()
```

And these are the models

```
from django.db import models
from .managers import InventoryManager
from shipment.models import Shipment


class MaterialType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, )
    is_toxic = models.BooleanField(default=False, )
    ...


class Material(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(MaterialType)
    lot_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    ...


class Batch(models.Model):
    batch_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, )
    ...


class Input(models.Model):
    """
    These are input materials to a batch.
    A batch may contain at most 1 toxic material.
    """
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material)
    ...


class Item(models.Model):
    id_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, )
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, )
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment, blank=True, null=True, )
    ...
    objects = models.Manager()
    inventory = InventoryManager()
```

I have removed all Fields which are not related to the query. The method works, but the output is incorrect...(It does not match the code in the description)

If anyone has a better solution than that expensive join, I would love to hear it.

**EDIT:** More details:

```
# imports go here

class BatchListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Batch
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BatchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items_non_toxic'] = Item.inventory.non_toxic_items()
        context['my_qs'] = []
        for batch in self.object_list:
            flag = False
            for my_input in batch.input_set.all():
                if my_input.material.type.is_toxic:
                    flag=True
            if not flag:
                for my_item in batch.item_set.all():
                    if my_item.shipment is None:
                        context['my_qs'].append(my_item)
        return context
```

{{ my_qs }} # returns 73 items

,     20,     21,     22,     23,     24,     25,     26,     27,     28,     29,     30,     31,     32,     14035,     14042,     14043,     14044,     14045,     14046,     14047,     14048,     14049,     14050,     14051,     14052,     14053,     14054,     14055,     14056,     14057,     14058,     14059,     14060,     14061,     14062,     14063,     14064,     14065,     14066,     14067,     14068,     14069,     14070,     14071,     14072,     14073,     14074,     14075,     14076,     14077,     14078,     14079,     14080,     14081,     14082,     14083,     14084,     14085,     14086,     14087,     14088,     14089,     14090,     14091,     14092,     14093,     14094,     14095,     14096,     14097,     14098,     14099,     14100, ,

{{ items_non_toxic }} # returns 115 items

4,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9,     10,     11,     20,     21,     22,     23,     24,     25,     26,     27,     28,     29,     30,     31,     32,     10000,     10001,     10002,     10003,     10004,     10005,     10006,     10007,     10008,     10009,     10010,     10011,     10012,     10013,     10014,     10015,     10016,     10017,     10018,     10019,     10020,     10021,     10022,     10023,     14035,     14042,     14043,     14044,     14045,     14046,     14047,     14048,     14049,     14050,     14051,     14052,     14053,     14054,     14055,     14056,     14057,     14058,     14059,     14060,     14061,     14062,     14063,     14064,     14065,     14066,     14067,     14068,     14069,     14070,     14071,     14072,     14073,     14074,     14075,     14076,     14077,     14078,     14079,     14080,     14081,     14082,     14083,     14084,     14085,     14086,     14087,     14088,     14089,     14090,     14091,     14092,     14093,     14094,     14095,     14096,     14097,     14098,     14099,     14100,     45361,     45362,     45363,     45364,     45365,     45366,     45367,     45368,     45369,     45370,

Comment: `It does not match the code in the description`, can we see the query, what output you expect and what output is being generated? And it's not possible to avoid expensive join if your db schema is like what you posted.

Comment: I have added more details. Would you like to see the Raw SQL query?

I am not sure if posting that would help. I don't want to write RAW sql, but I could if it comes down to it.

my_qs is the expected (correct) output.

items_non_toxic is the actual ouput. (incorrect)

Technically, they are both 'actual' output, one is generated using python, the other is the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This solution came from twigbog:

http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/20v1qi/stackoverflow_how_can_i_filter_across_multiple/cg7db8l

```
def non_toxic_items(self):
    return super(InventoryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
        shipment__isnull=True,
        ).exclude(batch__in=Batch.objects.filter(
                input__material__type__is_toxic=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#in describes what is happening behind the scenes for anyone interested.